# Pass variable to #each in handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have template that looks like this:

calling it:

```
  {{Gd-text-input label="Specify" name="Specify" key="entry.810220554" hideIf=true}}
```

The template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='components/Gd-radio-input'>
    {{log key}}
      {{#each content}}
        {{log key}}
        <div class="radiobutton">
          {{radio-button id=label value=label name=key }}
          <label {{bind-attr for="label"}}>{{label}}</label>
        </div>
      {{/each}}
  </script>
```

The first log key outputs asdf. The one inside the #each – loop is undefined. How can I tell the Each-loop about the variable or access it from outside the loop?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yea, i wrote an answer myself, but it seems I forgot to mark it as approved, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

view.key is what is needed, so

```
 {{log view.key}}
```

will output the variable-name